# How to change multiple States in one Class with Subclasses?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have here an class "Request". This Request can be in multiple States. A Request can have multiple SubRequests, which do change the States of the above Request.
-> Is there an way to properly design this?

Currently I have:

```
Request {
 public MyState SignatureState{get; set;}
 public MyState CheckedState{get; set;}
 public MyState ConfirmedState{get; set;}
 ....20 more
 
 public ICollection<SubRequest>? subs {get; set;}
}

SubRequest {
    public MyState SignatureState{get; set;}
     public MyState CheckedState{get; set;}
     public MyState ConfirmedState{get; set;}
     ....20 more    
}
```

SubRequests can be added at creation and while the Request is already running. When a SubRequest changes, the Request changes.

I basically just have a huge "switch" in a Logic class where I check and change everything. The states are mostly set by the User and when one is "Confirmed" then the next State can be modified.
Additionally there are different Requests like "LoanRequest", "StateAidRequest", which don´t need all the States. For this I have another "switch" where I set the States at the creation to "Not_Needed".

Is there an "better" way to do all of this? I can´t stop to feel that this is super clunky and ungly. I have checked out the State Pattern, but it does not seem to fit.

Edit:

```
public class Logic{
 public updateState(Request req){
  if(req.SignatureState==DONE) req.ChekedState=NEXT;    
  if(req.CheckedState==DONE) req.ConfirmedState=NEXT;
  ....
  if(req.LastState==DONE) req.CompletelyDone = true;
 }
 
 public StateChanged(Request req){
   req.COmpletelyDone=false;
 }

 public resetStates(Request req){


   req.SignatureState=NEXT;
   req.CheckedState = TO_BE_DONE;
   .....
     }
     }
```

And in the UI/Controller it will be checked if a State is NEXT, if so then the User is able to change it, otherwise it´s locked. "updateStates" will be called everytime a SubRequests State is changed.

Comment: What is `MyState` ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit, after more comments:

So, you really have "steps" in the requests. I would treat them as steps, and a request can have only one NEXT step. All preceding steps are DONE, and the following steps are TO_BE_DONE. You just need a "pointer" to the current NEXT step. If that step is accomplished, the request is Completed.
You have different kind of Requests. Well, you can define in every Request class an array with the steps according to that type of request. So the request must complete only the steps defined in the array, and in that particular order.
Example:

```
class LoanRequest
{
    Step[] steps = {Step.Signature, Step.Checked, ... Step.Last};
    int nextStep = 0;
}
enum Step
{
    Signature,
    Checked...
}
```

If nextStep == 0, that means that Signature step is the next one.

Comment: I added some Code.